# Vue component not recognised? Very basic setup. The "header" component has been registered but not used vue/no-unused-components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to get this header component to be recognised and it just isnt. I've tried messing setting eslint to strict, and messing with my syntax to no avail. I don't get it, this should be so simple. ANy help would be appreciated.

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <header />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import header from './components/header'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    header,
  }
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

**main.js**

```
 import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.ico">
    <title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      <strong>We're sorry but <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %> doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
    </noscript>
    <div id="app">
    </div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  </body>
</html>
```

**header.vue**

```
<template>
    <header>
        <h1>Component header</h1>
    </header>

</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'header',
};
</script>

<style>
    header {
      display: flex;
    }
</style>
```

Any help would be awesome. Thankyou.

Comment: I think `main.js` is not imported in the `index.html`.

Comment: Hey importing that into the head tag worked! Should it be imported into the header? Because the error is now gone, but the header content is still not showing, however the header style is now showing (the flex attribute).

Comment: see answer below ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `main.js`needs to be imported into the `index.html`:

```
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/js/main.js"></script>
  </body>
```

(using the correct path)

It is better to rename your header component to another word, because `<header>` is used as a standard tag name in `html`

Comment: This error showed: Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

Comment: Do you use `webpack` or `vite` as a bundler?  You cannot put Vue components directly on the server ...

Comment: He is obviously using Webpack (`htmlWebpackPlugin` in HTML). So no changes of `index.html` are needed. Problem is indeed in the name of the component - `[Vue warn]: Do not use built-in or reserved HTML elements as component id: header`

Comment: That was it! thankyou so much! I didnt get that vue warn.

Comment: I see, thanks. Overlooked the WebPack Plugin...